# fieldname showing in seperate page when i want in same page

Tags: crystal-reports

the crystal reports is showing firstname, lastname, job title and picture. Some employees can have more than one job title.

I have done a test page. I have created one record where employee has two job titles. I have to use the navigation buttons in the CrystalReportView to see what other job titles they have. There are no other records showing for other employees so what I have created is correct. I don't know if it is possible but could I avoid using navigation buttons and display more than one job title in single page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the help of grouping. Take the employee name as group header and group by the employee name, so you can fetch the records of the job title with respect to particular employee name.

Comment: @mhu - thanks that helped I used Group Expert and it solved the problem. Most appreciated